How to optimize performance for PostgreSQL logical replication with a large number of databases?
We are using PostgreSQL 16.4 on Debian 12.2 (16vcpu/64gb). We have a multi-tenant setup where each tenant has its own database.
We are facing issues with logical replication performance when handling a large number of tenants (around 150 databases on the same PG instance).
Our replication setup
Using phyical replication, we replicate data from master instance to a replica. Each of the 150 replication slots are created on the replica side.
Publications are created for a handful of tables (15-20) and we are using the default pgoutput decoding plugin.
We aren't using a subscriber server and instead consume the changes from a Windows service app using the Npgsql client. However, with around 150 databases,
we're noticing significant performance degradation on the replica server, specifically in terms of CPU usage.
Test case
We've created two test tables, structurally identical to the ones we're looking to replicate, in each of the tenant databases. We've then proceeded to
insert a total of about 12k records during a 30s period with different parameters(mainly the number of databases where the records were inserted and number of replication slots + pg configuration parameters).
It's important to note that the db server wasn't under pressure during these tests - no large number of inserts, no long-running transactions etc.
We initially conducted testing on a server with 6 vCPUs and 24 GB RAM.
Before increasing the max_worker_processes and max_logical_replication_workers from their default values, we've noticed that the time difference between the first insert and first message the server sent was minimal, but as more and more messages aggregated, the insert to server sending the message time increased to about 7s. After increasing the mentioned parameters, the message latency had decreased to about 1-2s, however the CPU usage remained at around 70-80%.
After observing high CPU utilization, we upgraded the hardware specifications to 16 vCPUs and 64 GB RAM and have seen a decrease in CPU usage - it dropped to about 40-50%. We ended up with the parameter configuration mentioned below.
Current configuration setup
max_replication_slots:              512
max_wal_senders:                    512
max_worker_processes:               512
max_logical_replication_workers:    511
logical_decoding_work_mem:          64 MB

We continued to look into server's performance with different combinations of active replication slots and targeted databases and these were the results:
Note: for each of these tests, a total of 12k records were inserted
Note 2: with 136 active slots and little to no traffic, the CPU remains idle.

136 active replication slots - inserts into 136 databases

CPU usage: 40-50%


136 active replication slots - inserts into 70 databases

CPU usage 40-50%


136 active replication slots - inserts into 50 databases

CPU usage 40-50%


136 active replication slots - inserts into 10 databases

CPU usage 40-50%


10 active replication slots - inserts into 10 databases

CPU usage 2-3%


50 active replication slots - inserts into 50 databases

CPU usage 20-25%


50 active replication slots - inserts into 10 databases

CPU usage 20-25%



With 10 active slots and inserts into the same 10 databases, the server uses 2-3% of the CPU. With 50 active slots and inserts into the same 10 databases as previous test, the server uses 20-25% of the CPU. The trend continues as the number of replication slots is increased. We've noticed that the rise in the CPU usage depends on the number of slots, regardless of the number of databases being targeted.
It is worth mentioning that current CPU average usage on the master and the replica (without logical replication) is around 5-10%, so this would make a huge difference.
Since we're expecting even larger traffic in production environment in the long run, any insights or recommendations for optimization would be greatly appreciated. We are able to upscale the CPU resources to some extent, which will (hopefully) resolve this for time being, but not indefinitely, and the issue will emerge again as the number of databases rises.

Have you done a test where you do logical replication directly from the master, rather than cascading it first to a physical replica before doing logical replication from there?

What is your metric for CPU usage?  Are you looking at load average, or "1 minus id" (both from top), or something else?

We use Glances tool and hypervisor to track the CPU usage, as a sum of user and system stats.
We've tried creating slots on master and have seen improvements in the CPU usage, even on the weaker machine (hardware wise). What could be causing the overhead on replica server in our initial setup?

In my hands, it seems like there is just a storm of context switches which dominate the CPU, and not something that PostgreSQL itself is doing.  But I'm not confident my setup is sufficiently like yours to draw reliable lessons from.  Also, I see high CPU usage but not high lag, so it just looks like the CPU is busy successfully doing what I want it to do.


that the rise in the CPU usage depends on the number of slots

You missed the word "active" in front of "slots", which is key. Each active slot means a separate WAL sender process consuming resources as it decodes the WAL file in search of the changes that it needs to send, as defined by the publication and the subscription.
The Postgres WAL file is "global" in the sense that it contains records that belong to all databases in the instance (cluster). The fact that you only insert data into a small subset of databases doesn't mean that only the affected WAL senders will be active. Indeed, all WAL senders will process all WAL records, although the majority of the senders will simply ignore the records that don't concern them.

Thank you for the clarification, we've figured something like that was happening.
What I'm interested in is, is there a way to optimize this? Or are there any alternative approaches to setting up logical replication?
We've tried using different decoding plugins, but to no avail. We've also thought of periodically disabling slots based on the incoming traffic, but since we need the replication to happen in real-time, this is not an option.
